# Show and plot zero values on ChartJS line graph when no data

Tags: javascript, php, charts, chart.js

I have a script that uses ChartJS for plotting the performance of a QR code in term of scans and unique users. The chart only plots interactions with the QR, skipping those days when there is no interaction with it.

I would like to include those days plotting 0 as value for that day in case no interaction happens. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

this is the code:

```
/* Display chart */
    new Chart(pageviews_chart, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: <?= $data->pageviews_chart['labels'] ?>,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: <?= json_encode(l('link_statistics.pageviews')) ?>,
                    data: <?= $data->pageviews_chart['pageviews'] ?? '[]' ?>,
                    backgroundColor: pageviews_gradient,
                    borderColor: pageviews_color,
                    fill: true
                },
                {
                    label: <?= json_encode(l('link_statistics.visitors')) ?>,
                    data: <?= $data->pageviews_chart['visitors'] ?? '[]' ?>,
                    backgroundColor: visitors_gradient,
                    borderColor: visitors_color,
                    fill: true
                }
            ]
        },
        options: chart_options
    });
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass 0 as the value. We cannot help with your back-end, without more information.